# Com o delphi, como posso desabilitar a tecla ESC para todos os aplicativos?

Tags: delphi

Preciso desabilitar o `esc` para todos os programas usando o Delphi.

Provavelmente o `form` tem que ficar sempre ativo e eu desabilito a tecla de um jeito parecido com o exemplo abaixo.

Meu código até agora:

```
procedure TForm2.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin

if Key = 27 then
ShowMessage('A tecla Backspace foi pressionada');

end;
```

Comment: a documentação tá em inglês, você sabe como eu configuro o AHK para bloquear o ESC ?

Comment: Faz muito tempo que não mexo com isso, nao lembro direito. Mas dê uma pesquisada, deve ter algum script já pronto pra isso.

Comment: não achei nada de como fazer isso com o AHK, se alguém puder me ajudar....

Comment: meu caro, sua pergunta está muito vaga!

Comment: Pra ajudar quem for tentar responder: O OP me disse nos comments que quer evitar que o ESC funcione em todas as aplicações, não só no form. Comentei que pra isso vai ser melhor usar um AHK ou coisa do tipo, pq com uma aplicação em delphi não vai resolver. Na verdade a pergunta não reflete bem a necessidade do OP.

Comment: desabilitar de todo o sistema, Windows 7, 8 ou xp, se puder poste o código q citou...

Comment: Não poderia simplesmente usar o regedit?

Comment: não, precisa ser um programa só para alterar o registro, to pesquisando bastante mas tá difícil...

Comment: Mas o regedit faz isso ué. Basicamente ele serve para consultar e alterar o registro.

Comment: Seria só rodar o regedit, ir até a chave "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Keyboard Layout" e por o valor desejado. Se não tiver "Scancode Map" na lista é só adicionar, provavelmente como novo valor binário.

Comment: e em vb como faz ?

Comment: @DBX8 nem precisava abrir, tem várias dessas pelo site :D http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15994/

Comment: @DBX8 se bem que não sei o que é melhor, se é bom esperar abrir e fechar alguma como duplicata. Aí fica a questão, qual é duplicata de qual, tem resposta nas duas. Fora que, se eu nao me engano, tem mais dessas :)

Comment: @DBX8 aguardo a resposta...

Comment: Utilizando o AHK, pasta inserir esta linha no script: "ESC::Return"

Answer (score 7):

Um modo para alcançar isso programando em *Delphi* é utilizar Ganchos([`Hooks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) *em inglês*).

Considere o seguinte exemplo(*testado no Delphi XE4*, **Aplicação visual**):

```pascal
{ Anula o funcionamento da tecla Esc }
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, 
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

  type
  tagKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT = record
  vkCode: DWord;
  scanCode: DWord;
  flags: DWord;
  time: DWord;
  dwExtraInfo: PDWord;
  end;
  TKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT = tagKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT;
  PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT = ^TKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  khk: HHOOK;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function KeyboardHookProc(Code: Integer; wParam : WPARAM; lParam : LPARAM): NativeInt; stdcall;
var
p:PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT;
begin
p := PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT(lParam);
if (Code = HC_ACTION) and (wParam = $0100) then
if (p.vkCode = VK_ESCAPE) then
Result := 1 else Result := CallNextHookEx(0, Code, wParam, lParam);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
khk := SetWindowsHookEx(13, KeyboardHookProc, hInstance, 0);
if khk = 0  then ShowMessage('Error on start hook')
else ShowMessage('Hook started');
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
UnhookWindowsHookEx(khk);
end;

end.
```

Isso vai instalar um gancho(*hook*) no sistema para interceptar a tecla <kbd>Esc</kbd> feito isso, poderemos alterar seu comportamento, tal como anular.

---

Agora outro exemplo(**Aplicação Console**) que anula o funcionamento da combinação das teclas <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

```pascal
{ Anula o funcionamento da combinação de teclas Alt + Tab }
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows;

type
  tagKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT = record
  vkCode: DWord;
  scanCode: DWord;
  flags: DWord;
  time: DWord;
  dwExtraInfo: PDWord;
  end;
  TKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT = tagKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT;
  PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT = ^TKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT;

var
  khk: HHOOK;
  MSG: tmsg;

function KeyboardHookProc(Code: Integer; wParam : WPARAM; lParam : LPARAM): NativeInt; stdcall;
var
  p:PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT;
begin
p := PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT(lParam);
if (Code = HC_ACTION) and (wParam = $0100) then
if (p.vkCode = VK_LMENU) or (p.flags = VK_TAB)  then
Result := 1 else Result := CallNextHookEx(0, Code, wParam, lParam);
end;

begin
khk := SetWindowsHookEx(13, KeyboardHookProc, hInstance, 0);
if khk = 0  then 
  writeln('Error on start hook') 
else 
  writeln('Hook started');

while GetMessage(MSG, 0, 0, 0) do begin
  TranslateMessage(MSG);
  DispatchMessage(MSG);
end;

UnhookWindowsHookEx(khk);
end.
```

<sub>para anular o <kbd>Alt</kbd> do lado direito use <kbd>VK_RMENU</kbd>*)</sub>

[`Aqui`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)(*Virtual-Key Codes*) você encontra o código das teclas.

Comment: Sou novo no delphi e queria saber como uso esse código, as mudanças das teclas eu sei fazer, só não sei como adicionar o código no formulário vcl

Comment: muito obrigado!!!

Comment: Sou novato no delphi e não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar nem no console nem no visual, mas só estou copiando e colando e alterando o nome do form, preciso fazer algo mais @DBX8 ? Estou usando o Embarcadero XE5, ele não dá erros, só q não bloqueia as teclas...

Comment: @user3230262 Não sei como você está desenvolvendo, então, vou disponibilizar um exemplo, [**baixe aqui o código**](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=62461509563074537032).

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado mesmo!!!

Comment: É possível bloquear o CTRL + ALT + DEL ? tentei e não deu certo...

Comment: Ok, Obrigado!!!

Answer (score 6):

#### Sobre o reconhecimento do evento do teclado

Se ao pressionar <kbd>ESC</kbd> sua mensagem não aparece, conforme definido em seu método **`FormKeyDown`**, então verifique se a propriedade **`KeyPreview`** do formulário foi definido como **`True`**.

#### Como anular a tecla

Dê preferência ao evento **`OnKeyPress`** e para anular a tecla faça:

```delphi
if key = #27 then
  key := #0;
```

Answer (score 5):

Resposta alternativa, usando o registro: basta criar um arquivo texto "qualquercoisa.reg" com estes dados:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,5b,e0,38,00,00,00,00,00
```

Tenha certeza que o nome é `qualquercoisa.reg` e não `qualquercoisa.reg.txt`. Salvando o arquivo, dê dois cliques nele, e aceite a importação.

> Atenção: só faça isso se tem certeza que isto vai atingir o resultado desejado.

Comment: como desabilitar o ctrl, alt, del, tecla do Windows, esc e tab pelo registro ?

Answer (score 3):

Achei uma solução!!!

Desabilitar <kbd>Esc</kbd> e <kbd>[image]</kbd>:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,05,00,00,00,00,00,5B,E0,00,00,5C,E0,00,00,5D,E0,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,00
```

E para desabilitar a combinação <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> e <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>:

1. Digite `gpedit.msc` na caixa de Executar do Windows e tecle <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Selecione `User Configuration` - `Administrative` - `Templates` - `System` - `Ctrl-Alt-Del Options`.
3. Dê um duplo clique em *Remover Alterar senha*, *Remover Bloquear computador*, *Remover Gerenciador de Tarefas* e 
   *Remover Logoff* e selecione *Ativar* e depois em **OK**.
4. Selecione `Computer Configuration` - `Administrative Templates` - `System` - `Logon`.
5. No painel da direita, dê um duplo clique sobre `Hide` para troca rápida de usuário.
6. Selecione `Enabled` e clique em **OK**.