# Como desabilitar combinação de teclas no windows pelo registro

Tags: windows-8, windows-7

Como desabilitar as teclas <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Del</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>[image]</kbd>, e <kbd>ESC</kbd> pelo registro do *Windows 7 e 8*?

consigo desabilitar a tecla <kbd>Esc</kbd> mas não o resto, segue exemplo da tecla <kbd>Esc</kbd>:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,5b,e0,38,00,00,00,00,00
```